# MySQL, UNION ALL with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS not working sometimes

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union-all

I'm having some problems with **UNION ALL** using **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** in **MySQL, InnoDB**. First let me show a simple database schema to explain what's going on...

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrB5J.jpg)

Media Table

```
media_id    title
-------------------------------------
1           Empire of the Sun
```

Genre Pattern Table

```
genre_id    name
-------------------------------------
1           Action
2           Adventure
```

Locale Table

```
locale_id    code
-------------------------------------
1            en_US
2            pt_BR
3            fr_FR
```

Genre Translations Table

```
genre_id    locale    translation
-------------------------------------
1           1         Action
1           2         Ação
2           1         Adventure
2           2         Aventura
```

Media Genres Table

```
media_id    genre_id
-------------------------------------
1           1
1           2
```

Now it's simple: *I need to return a genre name compatible with user locale*. Let's suppose that user locale is **pt_BR**. To I get results I use the follow SQL:

```
select gt.name
from media_genres mg
inner join genre_translation gt on (mg.genre_id = gt.genre_id)
where (mg.media_id = 1 and gt.locale_id = 2)
```

It returns:

```
name
-------------------------------------
Ação
Aventura
```

But, now, let's suppose that user locale is fr_FR. There's no translation for fr_FR, right? The solution I found was use a UNION ALL with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, then I use the following SQL:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS gt.name
from media_genres mg
inner join genre_translation gt on (mg.genre_id = gt.genre_id)
where (mg.media_id = 1 and gt.locale_id = 3)

UNION ALL

select  gt.name
from media_genres mg
inner join genre_translation gt on (mg.genre_id = gt.genre_id)
where FOUND_ROWS() = 0 and (mg.media_id = 1 and gt.locale_id = 1)
```

If there's no found rows for locale_id = 3 and media_id = 1, then I'll get the results for locale_id = 1 (default) and media_id = 1.

The problem is: *the statement sometimes return right data and sometimes return no data*.

And my main question: **why is this happening?**

Comment: I'm not sure there's a guarantee that the first `SELECT` is executed first, so you can't depend on `FOUND_ROWS()` in the second `SELECT` being the number of rows from the first one.

Comment: You should be getting an error, because the two subqueries don't return the same number of columns. Does the second subquery really return `mg.genre_id, gt.name` like the first one?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I had written wrong the field "mg.genre_id", even without this field in SQL... I have the same results: sometimes data is returned, sometimes not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is by using `LEFT JOIN` to join with the translation table, and then use `IFNULL` to supply a default when there's no match.

```
SELECT mg.genre_id, IFNULL(gt2.name, gt1.name) AS name
FROM media_genres AS mg
JOIN genre_translation AS gt1 ON mg.genre_id = gt.genre_id AND gt.locale_id = 1
LEFT JOIN genre_translation AS gt2 ON mg.genre_id = gt.genre_id AND gt.locale_id = 3
WHERE mg.media_id = 1
```

Comment: This worked well, I just fixed the "gt." to "gt1." and "gt2." in the join statement! Thank you so much. Is this query performance good?

Comment: It should be good as long as you have an index on `genre_translation.genre_id`.